# Dynmaic checkboxs validation

Tags: php, javascript

I want to validate Checkbox in javascript, checkboxes is generating dynamically by PHP and name of checkboxes are  like "checkbox1" , "checkbox2" ,"checkbox3" i.e. incrementing i++ and these numbers are coming from database, it might be first time only 2 rows fetched and next time 112 rows.

How i can make sure in javascript that atleast one checkbox must be selected.

Comment: You can do javascript validation, but if someone doesn't have javascript enabled then they will bypass that validation. Make sure you validate with php as well.

Comment: Yup what you are saying is correct but here problem is name of checkboxes...i can't use any in-bulid javascript terms like getElementById or getElementByName to get length of checkbox array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use any js framework, then just give the same `name` attribute to the checkboxes

Assuming your checkboxes are named `test`

```
var chkBoxes = document.getElementsByName("test");
  var chked=0;
  for(var i=0;i<chkBoxes.length;i++)
  {
    if(chkBoxes[i].checked)
        chked++;
  }
  if(chked===0)
     alert("Please select a value");
```

**Added as per the sample code specified in the comment**

```
function isChecked()
{
  var i=1; 
  var chkd=0;
  var elem = "";
  var chkForMoreChkBoxes=true;
  do{
        elem=document.getElementById("check_"+i);
        try{
            if(elem.checked)
            {
                chkd++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            chkForMoreChkBoxes=false;
        }
  }while(chkForMoreChkBoxes)
  if(chkd===0)
  {
    alert("Please select a value");
    return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: Here problem is checkbox name is dynamic and created by PHP code i.e. through Loop and box checkname always like checkbox20,checkbox21 etc so here i can't use code suggested by you.

Comment: Code example - <input type='checkbox' name='check_1' value='01' class='results1' id='check_1'
<input type='checkbox' name='check_2' value='02' class='results1' id='check_2'>, as example if we have checkboxes upto 100 and how we can identify checked checkboxes dynamically.

Comment: @Shatru : updated the code as per the example.Please check and revert if it works

Answer (score 2):

```
// When you use jQuery... somehow like this
$('form').submit(function() {
    if ($("input:checked").length == 0) {
        alert('Please check at least one checkbox!');
        return false;
    }
});
```